# Rails 3 and the gem devise_oauth2_providable cannot be installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, oauth-2.0

I am trying to setup an oAuth2 provider using the devise_oauth2_providable gem for devise.
The installation instructions on the website is very lacking and I do not know how to setup a client for example.

**Gem is found here:**
https://github.com/socialcast/devise_oauth2_providable

I need all pointers I can get! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late but here is good example of the client and server: https://github.com/aganov/devise-oauth2-provider-client

Comment: It's never too late, and thank you!  But wow, not even a readme to explain what it is.  Reading the code helps, tho'